# Is there a wood elf wife that you can marry?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am a wood elf so I would like to be married to a wood elf so is there any wood elf wives out there?

Comment: I'd argue there is a slight difference in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, there are no Bosmer wives (or husbands) out there. [The Elder Scrolls Wiki has a handy page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage) for determining who can be married.

If you are on PC you could browse the [Steam Workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=72850&requiredtags%5B%5D=NPCs) or [Nexus Mods](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/searchresults/?src_cat=33) to try to find a marriageable Bosmer NPC.

---

Additionally, if you are playing on PC, and are comfortable using console commands to alter the game, you could find a Wood Elf you would like to marry and force it to be possible. [A little further down the same TES Wiki page on marriage](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage#Forcing_marriage_.C2.A0PC.C2.A0.C2.A0):

> The marriage dialog option can be forced to appear on NPCs by opening the console, targeting the desired NPC, and typing the command "addfac 19809 1". This could possibly cause issues with NPCs who were not originally intended to have this option.
>
> A friendship must have been started with the NPC in the form of a quest, as their disposition (which is a hidden stat) needs to be of a certain level in order for them to recognize the Amulet of Mara. Alternatively the command "setrelationshiprank player 4" can be used after adding the person to the marriage faction. It is not possible to marry several of the people in the game, such as Ulfric Stormcloak.

Comment: @Jonsams [There are a handful of named female Bosmer NPCs in Skyrim](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bosmer_%28Skyrim%29#Notable_Bosmer). None of whom can be married without altering the game in some way.

Answer (score 4):

No. Unfortunately not.

The [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#NPCs_available_to_be_married) has a full list of all the spouses (male and female) and none are wood elves.